# Have a Query want it in LINQ(Inner Join)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm having problem translating a query to LINQ in C# this is my query

```
select PDF.Name,PDF.Name
from PDF inner join PC
on PDF.Id=PC.Ref_PDF
having pc.Ref_Customer=_id
```

you should know that  **_id** is something that i send to my method so I can find something with it

so far I did this which I don't think would work(cuase lot's of errors poped up)

> Invalid expression term 'select'

and

> Expected contextual keyword 'equals'

both at end of here `join p in Context.PDFs on c.Ref_PDF`

```
     internal List<EF_Model.PDF> Customers_File(int _id)
           {
               using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities())
                  {
                    var q = from c in Context.PCs
                            where c.Ref_Customer == _id
                            join p in Context.PDFs on c.Ref_PDF
                            select new { c.PDF.Id, c.PDF.Name, c.PDF.File };
                    return q;
                  }
           }
```

How can we make it into a linq statement?

Comment: Post the errors to get better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the syntax for the query

```
List<EF_Model.PDF> Customers_File(int _id) {
    using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities()) {
        var q = from c in Context.PCs
                join p in Context.PDFs on c.Ref_PDF equals p.Id
                where c.Ref_Customer == _id
                select new EF_Model.PDF { Id = c.PDF.Id, Name = c.PDF.Name, File = c.PDF.File };
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

and the method expects to return a list so use the `ToList()` on the query when returning from the method.

UPDATE:

If the intention was just to return the PDF model then no need to create the anonymous object just return `c.PDF`

```
List<EF_Model.PDF> Customers_File(int _id) {
    using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities()) {
        var q = from c in Context.PCs
                join p in Context.PDFs on c.Ref_PDF equals p.Id
                where c.Ref_Customer == _id
                select c.PDF;
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Included the model namespace to avoid conflict

Comment: tnx in advance,but why do we have to put pdf after new statement?

Comment: Or avoid creating a new object and just returning `c.PDF`

Comment: You do not have to if you are not building a new object.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job for you

```
from pc in context.PCs where pc.Ref_Customer == _id
join p in context.PDFs on pc.Ref_PDF equals p.Ref_PDF
select new {pc.PDF.Id, pc.PDF.Name, pc.PDF.File }
```

Probably when you said errors, I assume you saw synactical errors

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a navigation property, the query is:

```
var q =
  from pc in Context.PCs
  where pc.Ref_Customer == _id
  from pdf in pc.PDFs
  select pdf;
```

---

If you don't:

```
var q =
  from pc in Context.PCs
  where pc.Ref_Customer == _id
  join pdf in Context.PDFs on pc.Ref_PDF equals pdf.Id
  select pdf;
```

---

The main thing to know about the join syntax, it has the form

" join *(a)* in *(b)* on *(c)* equals *(d)* "

- *(a):* the new range variable for a member of *(b)*
- *(b):* the source of items you are joining to - the right side of the join.
- *(c):* an expression in which the item from the left side of the join is in scope.
- *(d):* an expression in which the item from the right side of the join is in scope - *(a).*